# Faster way to load drop down list

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, webforms

So I am having a problem loading a drop down list in an asp.net web forms site. I am pulling the records from a SQL Server database. I am binding the results to a drop down list.

My problems stems from the fact that I am retrieving 21500 plus rows and it is causing a long delay to the point where the browser throws a message asking if I want to stop a long executing script. If I wait long enough, ~2 minutes it will come back but still runs very slow taking a long time scroll down through the list.

Here is the VB code for the SQL call:

```
    Private Function GetCorInfo(field As String, tblname As String, Optional whereClause As String = "") As DataTable
    Dim sqlCmdTxt As String = "Select " & field & " From " & tblname
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(corConnection)
        Try
            conn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Master.message = "Unable to open SQL DB connection\nError: SQL101\nPlease contact the Help Desk for support.\n" & HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(ex.Message)
            jsa.alertmessage(passedPage, Master.message)
        End Try
        Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
            'Check for where clause
            If whereClause <> "" Then
                sqlCmdTxt = sqlCmdTxt & whereClause
                If whereClause.Substring(7, 6) = "cornum" Then
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cornum", ddl2.SelectedItem.Text)
                End If
            End If
            If field = "cornum" Then
                sqlCmdTxt = sqlCmdTxt & " Order By " & field & " Desc"
            End If
            sqlCmd.CommandText = sqlCmdTxt
            sqlCmd.Connection = conn
            Using sqlDT As New DataTable()
                Using sqlDA As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
                    Try
                        sqlDA.Fill(sqlDT)
                        Return sqlDT
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        conn.Close()
                        Master.message = "Unable to load list.\nError: SQL104\n" & HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(ex.Message)
                        jsa.alertmessage(passedPage, Master.message)
                        Return Nothing
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Then when the data table is returned I am binding it to the drop down list using this code:

```
                If Not IsNothing(dt) Then
                'Set ddl
                With ddl
                    'Turn on ddl
                    .Visible = True
                    'Set Data Source
                    .DataSource = dt
                    'Set Text Field
                    .DataTextField = field1
                    'Set Value Field
                    .DataValueField = field1
                    'Set variable to field value
                    'Bind Data
                    .DataBind()
                    'Assign Variable
                    field = ddl.SelectedItem.Text
                    'Check for ddl match
                    If whereClause <> "" AndAlso ddl1.SelectedIndex = 3 AndAlso ddl.ID = "ddl3" Then
                        .Items.FindByValue(field).Selected = True
                    ElseIf whereClause <> "" AndAlso ddl1.SelectedIndex = 3 AndAlso ddl.ID = "ddl4" Then
                        .Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select", "0"))
                    Else
                        'Insert first choice
                        .Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select", "0"))
                    End If
                    'Set to index 0
                    .SelectedIndex = 0
                End With
                Return 1
            Else
                Return -1
            End If
```

Both sets of codes are run in functions.

How can I speed this up? I have looked at using Session and View State but the number of returned records would cause a bigger slow down if I do that.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Maybe search instead of populating a drop down.

Comment: Wait, this is a drop-down that's going to have 21500 options to choose from?  Are people supposed to look through all of these options?  Something seems fairly odd about the UI here....

Comment: You could use an autocomplete instead....

Comment: It is a list of all current customers for the business.

No they don't look through, press the starting letter and jump to that section.

Wouldn't auto complete still need to have a full list verify against?

Comment: Don't populate a drop-down with 20k+ items.

Comment: then what would be a way to giver the user a list of the customers if not a drop down list?

Comment: That query makes me shiver. Have you heard of sql injection? Your code is extremely vulnerable. And I too am not surprised the performance sucks loading a combobox with 20,000 items. Without some context of what you are doing it is impossible to offer a better solution. But a combobox is not it.

Answer (score 0):

So this what i finally did.

Placed a text box for the user to type in the first few char's of a new customer name. Then taking that I build a SQL query that only returns records that match the chars entered.

Much faster and only have at max 35 records...

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries though. My friend bobby tables love code that builds up strings and executes them. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: This looks like a comment. not an answer

Comment: Sean Lange,
Even if there is no user entry of data. All choices are coming from drop down lists.